# Using ListView owner drawn DrawItem not the same size as the LargeIcon ImageSize

Tags: winforms, listview

I am using a ListView in LargeIcon view mode to show a list of images from an ImageList. I don't want the labels or subitems drawn, so I am using a OwnerDraw and a DrawItem event. However, I cannot seem to make the item size match the image size.

I have tried resizing the ImageList, as well as the images I am storing in the list, and while it does change the size of each item in the ListView, there is still "extra space" that is being drawn around the image that I can't get rid of.

Here is my DrawItem event:

```cs
private void listView_Boxes_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  ListView view = (ListView)sender;
  e.DrawDefault = false;
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(view.LargeImageList.Images[e.Item.ImageKey], 0, 0);
  e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

My ImageList ImageSize is set to 200x200, and the images I am building to put in that list are 200x200. But here is what the item is being drawn as:

[image: Bitmap image as LargeIcon for ListView item]

The dotted line is the DrawFocusRectangle, showing the extra space. I'm guessing that space is for the label and subitems, even though they aren't being drawn in? Is there a way to remove those using the DrawItem override?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: I'm guessing it has something to do with the read-only property of Bounds on the ListView.Item. If so, is there no way to override the Bounds, or to draw into the Bounds?

Comment: I would just center the image.

Comment: @LarsTech Well, that was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per @LarsTech, I just grabbed the Bounds rectangle and centered the image in that rectangle.

```cs
private void listView_Boxes_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  ListView view = (ListView)sender;
  e.DrawDefault = false;
  Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
  int width = rect.Width, height = rect.Height;
  int xPad = width - imageSize, yPad = height - imageSize;
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(view.LargeImageList.Images[e.Item.ImageKey], (int)(xPad/2), (int)(yPad)/2);
  e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```